# Why can't I vertical align this text?

Tags: css

I can't seem to get this text to align vertically. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? What I want is to center this "test" text with the center of the image on the left which is a submit button.

```
<input type="image" src="send.gif" name="send" value="" />
<span style="font-weight:bold;padding:0;margin-left:20px;vertical-align:middle">test</span>
```

---

Thanks guys.. Can't seem to figure this out. I've always had issues aligning vertically.

```
<div id="postcomments">
  <form method="post" action="comments.php">
    <div>
      <h2>Comments</h2>
      Name:<br />
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
      Email:<br />
      <input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
      Website:<br />
      <input type="text" id="site" name="site" />
      Story:<br />
      <select id="mute" name="mute">
        <option value="">hello</option>
      </select><br />
      Comments:<br />
      <textarea name="comment" rows="10" cols="46"></textarea><br /><br />
      <input type="image" src="send.gif" name="send" value="" />
      <span style="font-weight:bold;color:red;padding:0;margin-left:20px;vertical-align:middle">test</span>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: is this code in a table tag by any chance?

Comment: Can you please give us a surrounding html?

Comment: Just a side note (and you may already know this) but you should avoid using the `style` attribute and put everything in an external CSS file. Using it is just fine for testing though of course :)

Comment: Michael.. Let me ask you a question about this. I agree with you and I'm aware if this however.. Sometimes, when I will only ever need to align something once or apply a style to an element just one time, it kind of seems senseless to add this to a stylesheet. Am I wrong? I hate clutter is all. What are your tyhoughts?

Comment: My personal thoughts are that one-off style information is OK to put in a <style> tag on the page itself, but not in an inline style. An external stylesheet in this case would mean choosing between one-off styles hanging around in a main site stylesheet or having an external css file for every page on your site.

That being said, there's no real right or wrong answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alignment in this case should be applied to the image and not the span. You can use the "align" property of the INPUT tag to accomplish this:

```
<input type="image" src="send.gif" name="send" value="" align="middle" />
<span style="font-weight:bold;padding:0;margin-left:20px;">test</span>
```

Alternatively, using CSS:

```
<input type="image" src="send.gif" name="send" value="" style="vertical-align: middle" />
<span style="font-weight:bold;padding:0;margin-left:20px;">test</span>
```

Comment: Just want to point out that the `align` attribute for images is not valid HTML5 and looking forward it's probably best to use CSS.

Comment: Thank you Ryan. You got it. I used the inline css inside the input tag.

Answer (score 2):

You should have the `vertical-align: middle` applied to the image element, not the span. This should work:

```
<input type="image" src="send.gif" name="send" value="" style="vertical-align:middle" />
<span style="font-weight:bold;padding:0;margin-left:20px;">test</span>
```